# How do I get all different property values of a ruby DataMapper::Collection?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-datamapper

I'm using `ruby 1.9.3` and ruby-datamapper with `postgresql`. I have got a table full of entries, each of them has three properties: `id` ,`text` and `created_at`. The last one is a `Date` object.

In my application I `SELECT` some entries like so: `collection = Entry.all(:text => /SomeRegexp/)`. I now want to know all **different** values of `created_at` that occur in the returned `DataMapper::Collection` . I thought of the following two ways:

1. Iterate through the `DataMapper::Collection` and collect all dates.

   ```
   dates = Array.new
   Entry.all(:text => /SomeRegexp/).each { |entry| dates.include?(entry.date) ? next : dates = dates << entry.date }
   ```

   **Pros:**

   - It should work

     ---

   **Cons:**

   - It's slow for massive amounts of data

     ---
2. Ask the database for entries of each day and collect dates where collection != nil

   ```
   dates = Array.new
   for date in DatabaseStartDate..Date.today
     Entry.all(:created_at => date, :text => /SomeRegexp/).empty? ? next : dates = dates << date)
   end
   ```

   **Pros:**

   - Should be faster than the example above, especially with big amounts of data

     ---

   **Cons:**

   - Many Database queries

---

*NOTICE: The code above is untested pseudo code, it should just give readers a rough idea of what the real code should do, so it's not likely to work. If you need a more detailed example feel free to comment, I will try to explain it better then!*

*NEXT NOTICE: If you find errors in the pseudo code please tell me, so I can get started faster! ;)*

So finally my question is: Which solution should I prefer or is there a better one that didn't come into my mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third option: Raw SQL.

```
repository(:default).adapter.select('SELECT created_at FROM entries WHERE text SIMILAR TO ' + pattern)
```

where pattern will be an expression like those in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: thank you very much! You forgot the `DISTINCT`, but the idea is awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made some tests, here are my results:

Solution #1 is a bit faster for small amounts of data, but for >10_000 records the second solution is clearly faster.

It's possible to improve performance for both solutions with selecting only the elements one needs eg. `Entry.all(:text => /SomeRegexp/, :fields => [:id, :date])`

Both code snippets worked for me.

If you know a better solution (maybe something built into datamapper or even postgresql) please reanswer the question! ;)